# This chain of CSS animation should run infinitely but it doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ecmascript-6, css-animations

I have this simple set of CSS animations that I want to run indefinitely. But for some reason, it only runs twice and stops.

Here's a [CodePen example.](https://codepen.io/abarcenas29/pen/aVbwEV)

Here is how I implement it using Jquery (this is also seen on the code)

```
$('#slide1').one(animationEnd, () => {
    $('#slide1').css('display', 'none').removeClass('animate-1')
    $('#slide2').css('display', '').addClass('animate-2')
  })

  $('#slide2').one(animationEnd, () => {
    $('#slide2').css('display', 'none').removeClass('animate-2')
    $('#slide3').css('display', '').addClass('animate-3')
  })

  $('#slide3').one(animationEnd, () => {
    $('#slide3').css('display', 'none').removeClass('animate-3')
    $('#slide1').css('display', '').addClass('animate-1')
  })
```

See that `#slide3` should revert to `#slide1` for animation. It did, but it stops after 2 cycles.

Comment: You have defined counter variable as const, but it needs to be let to allow later reassignment.

Comment: Sorry, corrected that. But that's not the issue.  @MartinAdámek

Comment: I think jQuery `.one` is supposed to only execute once. `The .one() method is identical to .on(), except that the handler for a given element and event type is unbound after its first invocation`. See more info : http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @Nouphal.M `.on` did it. Thanks!

Comment: The loop is infinite, for me (at codepen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `counter` variable as `const`, but it needs to be `let` to allow later reassignment.

```
let counter = 0;
```

Also you need to use `$.on` instead of `$.one` when binding to the animation end. `$.on` is used to bind handler to some event (every time it occurres), while `$.one` is used for one time binding only (run the handler first time the event occurres, but no more that that).

Here is your updated example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WXNOKQ

Answer (score 0):

answer already given and accepted, this is only for infos since the javaScript takes only three boxes into account.

`animation-delay` can be used to keep animation looping infinitly:

```css
body {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #27292d;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #27292d url('bg.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.slider-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 40%;
}

.slider-content {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.boxes {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-box {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.sub-box span {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: #FF4F80;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: #4CA2F0;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: #53CEC8;
}

@keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    transform: translate(100px, 200px) scale(0)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(100px, 200px) scale(0)
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-100px) scale(1.5)
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(-100px) scale(1.5)
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-100px) scale(1.5)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(100px, -200px) scale(0)
  }
}

.slider-single {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.animate-1 {
  transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(.17, .67, .55, 1.43);
  animation: ease-out heartbeat 6s -3s infinite;
}

.animate-2 {
  transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(.17, .67, .55, 1.43);
  animation: ease-out heartbeat 6s -1s infinite;
}

.animate-3 {
  transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(.17, .67, .55, 1.43);
  animation: ease-out heartbeat 6s 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-content">

    <div id='slide1' class="slider-single animate-1">
      <div class=''>
        <p class='boxes box1'>Pink Header</p>
      </div>
      <div class='sub-box'>
        <span>White Header</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id='slide2' class="slider-single animate-2">
      <div>
        <p class='boxes box2'>Another Header</p>
      </div>
      <div class='sub-box'>
        <span>subheader</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id='slide3' class="slider-single animate-3">
      <div>
        <p class='boxes box3'>10 more to go</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-content">
    <div id='slide1' class="slider-single animate-1">
      <div class=''>
        <p class='boxes box1'>Pink Header</p>
      </div>
      <div class='sub-box'>
        <span>White Header</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='slide2' class="slider-single" style='display:none;'>
      <div>
        <p class='boxes box2'>Another Header</p>
      </div>
      <div class='sub-box'>
        <span>subheader</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='slide3' class="slider-single" style='display:none;'>
      <div>
        <p class='boxes box3'>10 more to go</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```